# Restart task if is already running

Tags: visual-studio-code, task

i have this task that is server for my application:

```
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "f1",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "gunicorn",
        "args": [
            "main:api"
        ],
        "isBackground": true,
    },
]
```

is mapped on key "F1", now, if this task is active, when i press F1, i want to kill it and start again.
So i don't have to press CTRL-C each time i write new function.

How i can implement this behaivor?
- Thanks

Comment: Have you tried with "Restart running task" command?

Comment: i'm searching for behaivor like this one:https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6578

but seems it's not implemented

Comment: @GiovanniCardamone did you find the solution?

Answer (score 16):

As suggested by @jahuuar, there's a command for this:

Open the command palette (CMD/CTRL + Shift + P or Menu>View>Command Palette) and type "restart", you'll see "**Tasks: Restart Running Task**". If that's what you are looking for (it will ask for the task to restart, even if there is only one... Oo), you can then map a keyboard shortcut to that command.

Comment: Isn't there a way to define this behavior as default in the `tasks.json`?

Comment: I don't think so. I've added keyboard shortcut for this `Tasks: Restart Running Task`

Comment: There's a way with bash pokery, see my answer.

Answer (score 11):

As per **Visual Studio Code Version 1.39.0** , You can right click the Output Area and choose

> "Stop Code Run"

.
Hope this is what you are looking for.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

[image]

in the output area you can "Stop Code Run"

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to restart my task always without getting the annoying prompt, it was either there's a way to do it only by using the linux shell or I will make an extension for vscode.

First, lets think about the easy path (probably), using the shell. How would we proceed to always restart a hanging script if we only had `xterm`s ?
We try to find the process by the command line and kill them, then we start the newer one.

Lets say we are debugging a shell script named **stages.sh**.

```bash
ps -A -o pid=,cmd= | grep stages.sh | grep -P -o '^[ ](\d+)'| xargs kill -KILL
```

That will kill all previous instances. But that's no good, we can do a neat trick by using the internal `exec` to fork the bash process with a different process name.

```bash
exec -a my-task bash ./stages.sh
```

```
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
monad     271915  0.0  0.0  11324  5912 pts/1    Ss+  Jul20   0:00 /usr/bin/bash
monad     272177  0.0  0.0   9420  5400 pts/2    Ss+  Jul20   0:00 /usr/bin/bash
monad     342891  0.0  0.6 4885572 112040 pts/6  Ssl+ Jul21   1:30 /usr/bin/pwsh-preview -NoProfile -EncodedCommand SQBtAHAAbwByAHQALQBNAG8AZAB1AGwAZQAgACcALwBoAG8AbQBlAC8AbQBvAG4AYQBkAC8ALgB2AHMAYwBvAGQAZQAtAHMAZQByAHYAZQB
monad     544486  0.5  2.2 8948900 375132 pts/7  Ssl+ 10:31   2:01 buckd -Dbuck.is_buckd=true -Dbuck.buckd_launch_time_nanos=672292609941292 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=15000 -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=0 -XX
monad     588089  0.0  0.0   9608  6360 pts/3    Ss   16:11   0:00 /usr/bin/bash
monad     588182  0.0  0.0   7076  3632 pts/3    S+   16:12   0:00 my-task ./stages.sh
monad     604842  0.0  0.0   7076   404 pts/3    S+   16:40   0:00 my-task ./stages.sh
monad     604843  0.0  0.0   5552   740 pts/3    S+   16:40   0:00 cat
monad     604844  0.0  0.0   5712   676 pts/3    S+   16:40   0:00 xargs echo --config-file
monad     604936  0.1  0.0   9608  6304 pts/9    Ss   16:40   0:00 /usr/bin/bash
monad     604986  0.0  0.0  10064  3448 pts/9    R+   16:41   0:00 ps au
```

Nice, now its easier to find the correct task to kill. And now `pkill` can work too.

```bash
pkill -KILL -f my-task
```

Now that we found a way to restart a shell task, we just need to make *vscode* task script. We know that if the shell process dies, the task ends and vscode reuse the terminal, we also know that we forked the process, so if the child dies, the parent bash dies too.

So we get

```js
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "kill-buck",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "pkill -KILL -f vscode-task && exit 0"
        },
        {
            "label": "buck",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "exec -a vscode-task bash ${workspaceFolder}/stages.sh",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
        }
    ]
}
```

That creates the task and we can manually kill it with *ctrl+shift+p* and *run task* *kill-buck*, but that's no good, we can do better.

Its possible to serialize the tasks to run in sequence.

```js
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "kill-buck",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "pkill -KILL -f vscode-task && exit 0"
        },
        {
            "label": "buck",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "exec -a vscode-task bash ${workspaceFolder}/stages.sh",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "dependsOn": ["kill-buck"],
            "dependsOrder": "sequence"
        }
    ]
}
```

That's better, but we still have the pesky warning. So, finally we add one last trick to get rid of it.

There's a special property on ***runOptions*** called ***instanceLimit*** to set up the number of concurrent runs we allow.

As we are starting a new run while we are leaving the other running and because we are going to kill them any way, we can trick *vscode* into thinking that we are going to have more than 1 instance.
But as we kill all the previous others before by using another task, the *bash* process will die and free the same task to be used again, there will be only one instance, and *vscode* **will** reuse the same window.

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "kill-buck",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "pkill -KILL -f vscode-task && exit 0"
        },
        {
            "label": "buck",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "exec -a vscode-task bash ${workspaceFolder}/stages.sh",
            "problemMatcher": [],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "runOptions": {
                "instanceLimit": 999
            },
            "dependsOn": ["kill-buck"],
            "dependsOrder": "sequence"
        }
    ]
}
```

And that does what we wanted.

Comment: Dissecting how `automatic` works. I haven't tried this for a running npm instance but I will post one if I successfully create one.

Answer (score 1):

## There are two ways I know of

1. First on the output area in vscode right click on the empty area and you'll have a window with an oprion to stop the code run
2. Setting up the `vscode` code runner to run in terminal

[image: Code running initially without stopping]

Open the settings window and search for `run in terminal`
[image: Settings window]

On the checkbox `Code-runner:Run In Terminal` ensure the checkbox is checked
[image: Checked checkbox]

Close the settings window and run your code again. If it does't take effect reload or restart your `vscode`

You should see something like this when you run your code again
[image: Running in terminal safe]

Your code now runs in the terminal and you can easily terminate using `CTRL + C`

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @Luiz Felipe's answer:

Goal: To restart a task without clicking the prompt

Process: Determine the task you need to terminate, if determined kill the task, then run the process

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "kill-npm-first",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "PID=( $(ps aux | grep node || true | awk '{print $2}') ); kill -9 PID \"${PID[2]}\" || true && exit 0;"
    },
    {
        "label": "ns",
        "type": "npm",
        "problemMatcher": [],
        "script": "start",
        "runOptions": {
          "instanceLimit": 999
        },
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
        },
        "dependsOn": ["kill-npm-first"],
        "dependsOrder": "sequence",
        "detail": "node --max-old-space-size=1536 --preserve-symlinks bin/www"
    }
  ]
}
```

Output:

- If task `ns` (`ns - npm start`) is not yet running it will spawn a new task
- If any task named `ns`, spawn a new task window
- It doesn't close the first task window
- Successfully terminates the first task
- Creates 2 terminal windows in vscode (if there's one instance running)
- If there are two existing task windows, it will rerun the task interchangeably (eg. two tasks `ns` are running, execute task ns again, and it will rerun the script in the first task window and consecutively)

Feel free to comment if you see any improvement in this script.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that u are running code in terminal rather than output section for that

1. go to settings
2. go to extension
3. Run configuration
   4.(scroll little bit  ) u find
   Run  in terminal
4. check that box close vs code and run the program again
   hope it helps enjoy coding

Answer (score 0):

Example of AutoHotkey script that would press the `Restart Task` button after issuing a `Ctrl+B`.

```
Left(lx, ly, ls, lt)
{
  MouseMove, lx, ly, ls
  Send {LButton down}
  Sleep lt
  Send {LButton up}
  Sleep 31
}

#If WinActive("ahk_exe Code.exe")

; Win+B to automatically restart the build task
#b::
  MouseGetPos mx, my
  Send ^b
  Sleep 314
  WinGetPos, wx, wy, w, h, ahk_exe Code.exe
  xx := w - 321
  yy := h - 123
  ;ToolTip wx= %wx% wy= %wy% w= %w% h= %h% xx= %xx% yy= %yy%
  ImageSearch, x, y, %xx%, 1, %w%, %h%, *123 c:\VSCode-RestartTask.png
  if (ErrorLevel = 0)
  {
    ;ToolTip x= %x% y= %y%
    Left(x, y, 2, 123)
  }
  MouseMove, mx, my, 2
  ToolTip
  Return
```

Example of the picture used as `VSCode-RestartTask.png`. Though one would likely need to make a fresh capture in order to account for system-specific scaling, etc.

[image]

p.s. Another option is to bind the "*Terminal: Kill the Active Terminal Instance*" Keyboard Shortcut to a separate key and to press them both in a sequence.

I have it bound to `Ctrl+W`

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+w",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.kill"
},
```

hence the restart script is

```
#If WinActive("ahk_exe Code.exe")

#b::
  Send ^w
  Sleep 31
  Send ^b
  Return
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar problem creating tasks that would open a monitor terminal (therefore would not close at the end of the execution, <s>because there would be no end of execution</s>).
To go around this issue, I assigned the same keybind I had for running the task to the **Restart Task** command, but only if there was any task running, adding this to my `keybindings.json`:

```json
    {
        "key": "ctrl+shift+b", // replace with your running task keybind
        "command": "workbench.action.tasks.restartTask",
        "when": "taskRunning"
    },
```

It may not be the best approach, since it will assume you want to restart a task if **any** task is running, but if there is only one task in your workspace, it'll do.